# Display image from URI with "content://" scheme with Glide on Android Q

Tags: android, android-glide, android-contentresolver, mediastore, android-10.0

Questions around Android Q and Glide have been asked before but I'm not able to put them all together, so I hope someone is willing to help.

I'm saving images, downloaded from the cloud(Firebase) or chosen from gallery or taken with the camera, to local storage. I used to save it in the app's folder and could add it to the gallery, but with Android Q that is not possible anymore. So I changed my app to use the MediaStore and ContentResolver to access files and save it. Files are saved in the `Pictures` directory of `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`.

StorageHandler:

```
public Uri createUriForFile(String fileName, String parentId)
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    {
        Uri uriFromContentResolver = getUriFromContentResolver(fileName);
        if(uriFromContentResolver != null)
        {
            return uriFromContentResolver;
        }else
        {
            ContentResolver resolver = baseActivity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, EXTERNAL_PICTURE_RELATIVE_PATH);
            return resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        }
    }else {
        File pictureFile  = new File( EXTERNAL_PICTURE_STORAGE_DIR.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + parentId + File.separator + fileName );
        checkAndCreatePictureDir(parentId);
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(baseActivity, baseActivity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", pictureFile);
    }
}

public Uri getUriFromContentResolver(String fileName)
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    {
        ContentResolver resolver = baseActivity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

        Cursor queryCursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH}, MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + "=? ",
                new String[]{fileName}, null);

        if (queryCursor != null && queryCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            Uri content = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendEncodedPath(queryCursor.getString(queryCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH)))
                    .appendPath(queryCursor.getString(queryCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))).build();
            return content;
        } else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }else
    {
        return null;
    }
```

It saves the file to the storage, it can be seen with the Device Explorer in Android Studio. It is also uploaded to the cloud and can be viewed from there(if it is a new file). But when I'm trying to load it into a `ImageView` with Glide, it gives me an error: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown or unsupported URL: content://`. And I can't seem to figure out why. It used to work and the URI should be correct as it is used on other places as well(uploading the file, saving the file, etc.) and it works. What is the problem with Glide/my code?

Full error:

```
E/GlideExecutor: Request threw uncaught throwable
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown or unsupported URL: content://media/external/images/media/Pictures/**AppName**/IMG20200112164646.jpg
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:151)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:705)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1687)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1503)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1187)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResourceFromUri(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:85)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:60)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:15)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:272)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
```

Comment: Tried using [DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile.html?hl=en) and `fromSingleUri` or `fromTreeUri` instead of File class?

Comment: The error is not in the part where i use the `File` class, that is only used in versions prior Android Q. That part works, it's solely the part where I use `ContentResolver` and `MediaStore` which I can't get working. Using `File` and an `absolutePath` is deprecated in Android Q and can only be made working by enabling legacy storage. Which I don't want, because I need to fix it for future versions anyhow.

Comment: Sorry i misread your question. My bad :)

Comment: No problem sir, always appreciated when someone takes the time to write a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getUriFromContentResolver()` is wrong. Query for the `_ID`, then use `ContentUris.withAppendedId()` to assemble the `Uri` to use.

For example, in [this sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Q), I use:

```
  suspend fun getLocalUri(filename: String): Uri? =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      val resolver = context.contentResolver

      resolver.query(collection, PROJECTION, QUERY, arrayOf(filename), null)
        ?.use { cursor ->
          if (cursor.count > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            return@withContext ContentUris.withAppendedId(
              collection,
              cursor.getLong(0)
            )
          }
        }

      null
    }
```

where `PROJECTION` and `QUERY` are:

```
private val PROJECTION = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)
private const val QUERY = MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ?"
```

and where `collection` is:

```
  private val collection =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(
      MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL
    ) else MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

(in my case, I am querying videos; you would use `MediaStore.Images` instead)

Comment: Oh man, this is stupid. I tried this already a couple of days ago but it didn't work(something else was wrong in the code). After making everything work I forgot that I needed to try this again and see if this helps. Thanks for the answer!