# Use Glide to display an image saved into external storage MediaStore

Tags: file, storage, android-glide, mediastore, android-11

Before last [Android 11 update](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage), I used to get the file path of my  external image to display it on Glide. Because of the last update, I now need to use MediaStore storage option to store my images in external. I successfully save my images but I have a problem retrieving it and displaying it on glide.
I tried to use the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716014/display-image-from-uri-with-content-scheme-with-glide-on-android-q) to get the uri :

```
public Uri getUriFromContentResolver(String fileName) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
             ContentResolver resolver = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

            Cursor queryCursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH}, MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + "=? ",
                    new String[]{fileName}, null);

            if (queryCursor != null && queryCursor.moveToFirst()) {

                return ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, queryCursor.getLong(0));
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And retrieve it to display it on glide :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            Uri uriFromContentResolver = new ImageManager(context).getUriFromContentResolver(listPicture.get(pos).getFileName());

            if (uriFromContentResolver !=null) {
                System.out.println("Uri " + uriFromContentResolver.toString());

                Glide.with(context)
                        .load(uriFromContentResolver)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_24_black)
                        .into(pictureGallery);
            }

        } else {

            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(listPicture.get(pos).getPath())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_24_black)
                    .into(pictureGallery);
        }
```

I also tested glide to load with the path from uri.getPath() when I save the file using this :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
                fos = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
               

                String path = imageUri.getPath();
```

I'm not used to the MediaStore system, I will take any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a class to get the Uri of the file by using the file name

```
Uri uriFromContentResolver = getUriFromContentResolver(fileName);
```

```
public Uri getUriFromContentResolver(String fileName) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

            Cursor queryCursor = resolver.query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL),
                    new String[]{
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH},
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ?",
                    new String[]{fileName}, null);

            if (queryCursor != null && queryCursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                return ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(
                                MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL),
                        queryCursor.getLong(0));
            } else
            {
                return null;
            }

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Once we have it we call this function with the Uri we just got to get a Path

```
String path = getRealPathFromURI(uriFromContentResolver);
```

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
```

And with this path, Glide can read the file

```
Glide.with(context)
         .load(path)
         .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_24_black)
         .into(pictureGallery);
```